# Generalize a class' member from a specific container type (of pointers to itself)

Tags: c++, oop

Suppose you have the following class:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Node {
public:
    T data;
    std::vector<Node*> children;
};
```

I excluded its methods because I want to focus on a different point: the developer is constrained to use `std::vector` as a container for `children`.

In the context of *programming to an abstraction*, I'd like to learn how to make `std::vector` easily interchangeable with:

1. another container from the STL
2. an abstract class, with its own set of methods (potentially something that could become, or fulfilled with, a `std::vector`, `std::map`, `std::list`, etc.)

What ways do you know to accomplish this goal, and what are their main advantages and disadvantages?

Would C++20's Concepts help with this task? If so, I'd like to learn both the old and the new way.

Comment: First, you need to define the operations you are going to do with `children`.  Once you know all the ways you want to use it, then you can figure out what type of containers can support those operations.  Then you can write a trait for that.

Comment: Assuming the actions are "add a child" and "remove a child", how would you take advantage of type traits? And what about C++20's concepts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an additional template template parameter, like this:

```
template<template <typename...> typename Container, typename T>
class Node {
public:
    T data;
    Container<Node*> children;
};
```

and then instantiate `Node` with different containers:

```
Node<std::vector, int> n;
Node<std::set, int> m;
```

However, if you want to do something like

```
Node<std::map, int> m;
```

you will run into issues because `map` needs at least 2 template parameters, and you are only using `Node*`.

Before trying out any particular implementation strategy, I suggest you think about how you want to *use* the `Node` class, since this will inform the implementation.

Comment: I see the problem with `map`. How can the code be modified to support both a vector or a map? Let's assume that the actions on a `Node` are "add a child" and "remove a child". How would you proceed? Could type traits or concepts help?

Comment: @psq The issue is here: `Container<Node*>`. If you use a `map`, then you get `map<Node*>`, which doesn't work, because `map` needs at least 2 template parameters. This problem exists regardless of what a `Node` actually is. You need to also decide what `Container` should be. e.g. how would you use it if it could be either a `map` or a `vector`?

Comment: Sorry, I was too focused on the technicalities (the desire to learn how to manage a variable number of template arguments for `Container`) and I missed the fact that a `map` would need a key and value to be handled.
Maybe `vector` and `set` would have made more sense, and not even then... because `set` can't contain duplicates.
My point was to learn how to generalize a class as much as possible, but I can see how this is difficult without specifying some requirements. I consider this answer complete, thank you for the help!